# How to run swift command while staying on breakpoint in XCode?

Tags: xcode

In JetBrains's IDEs there is a option to launch custom commands while staying on breakpoint. Is there same functionality in XCode?

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click on a breakpoint
- Select "Edit breakpoint"
- Define an action

[image]